# jquery - passing multiple arguments to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

How do I pass multiple arrays to a controller in jquery without using JSON?

```
var Test1 = {};
Test1.Source = 'String1';
Test2.Type = 'String2';

var Test2 = {};
Test2.Name = 'String3';
Test2.Location = 'String4';
```

My controller is

```
public Int64 Method1(Class1 cl1, Class2 cl2)
{
}
```

What is the correct syntax for the data property of $.ajax()?
With one argument, I can have

```
data: Test1
```

However, how does this work with two or more arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap in another object, like this, so that each array (object actually) is a property:

```
data: {t1: Test1, t2: Test2 }
```

You can see an example of this in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (although with string values instead).

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for arrays. tried data: { cl1: Test1, cl2: Test2 }